# Looping an array in a batch-file

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop

I've read many questions and no solution seems to be what I need

I'm trying to have a list of strings and iterate overthem with commands

For example I have:

```
set x_array=Hello Goodbye Something Test

for %%s in (%x_array%) do (
   %WINZIP% WORD_%%s.zip -rp -ex %filepath%
)
```

EDIT: I'm trying to be able to loop over so I can create files called WORD_Hello.zip WORD_Goodbye.zip etc.. But whenever I do this the array says it's empty.

Comment: What is your problem, not just your task.

Comment: `$WINZIP%` is wrong syntax. What do you expect and what do you get? Run the batch in an open cmd window, set `echo on`  and insert an echo to see what happens.

Comment: @LotPings that was a typo here.

Comment: Can you provide output/error message produced in cmd?

Comment: @SamuelDenty No error comes up it just shows word_%s.zip instead of the element.

Comment: There definitly was an error, here my german locale output `"do(" kann syntaktisch an dieser Stelle nicht verarbeitet werden.`

Comment: @LotPings That's just a typo here, the real problem was my array in my script had an extra space.

Comment: Just a comment: an [array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_data_structure) and a [list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_(abstract_data_type)) are two _entirely different_ things!

Comment: @Aacini I know, it's just a bad habit from working with python a lot. I interchange the two easily in same sentences.

Comment: Wow! I didn't knew that in python an array and a list are the same! I can't understand how in python you can access an array element without a subscript, or how to manage a two-dimensional list...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a missing space following the do, so either

```
set x_array=Hello Goodbye Something Test
for %%s in (%x_array%) do (
   %WINZIP% WORD_%%s.zip -rp -ex %filepath%
)
```

or as the parentheses aren't necessary here:

```
set x_array=Hello Goodbye Something Test
for %%s in (%x_array%) do %WINZIP% WORD_%%s.zip -rp -ex %filepath%
```